# How to use mutable collections in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, mutable

I think I may be failing to understand how mutable collections work. I would expect mutable collections to be affected by applying map to them or adding new elements, however:

```
scala> val s: collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = collection.mutable.Seq(1)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> s :+ 2 //appended an element
res32: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)

scala> s //the original collection is unchanged
res33: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> s.map(_.toString) //mapped a function to it
res34: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[java.lang.String] = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> s //original is unchanged
res35: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)

//maybe mapping a function that changes the type of the collection shouldn't work
//try Int => Int

scala> s.map(_ + 1)
res36: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2)

scala> s //original unchanged
res37: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)
```

This behaviour doesn't seem to be separate from the immutable collections, so when do they behave separately?

Comment: The problem is that both methods map and :+ return new collections, they don't change the collection in place.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For both immutable and mutable collections, `:+` and `+:` create new collections. If you want mutable collections that automatically grow, use the `+=` and `+=:` methods defined by [**`collection.mutable.Buffer`**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html).

Similarly, `map` returns a new collection — look for `transform` to change the collection in place.

Answer (score 6):

`map` operation applies the given function to all the elements of collection, and **produces a new collection**.

The operation you are looking for is called `transform`. You can think of it as an in-place `map` except that the transformation function has to be of type `a -> a` instead of `a -> b`.

```
scala> import collection.mutable.Buffer
import collection.mutable.Buffer

scala> Buffer(6, 3, 90)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(6, 3, 90)

scala> res1 transform { 2 * }
res2: res1.type = ArrayBuffer(12, 6, 180)

scala> res1
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(12, 6, 180)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method never modifies the collection on which you call it. The type system wouldn't allow such an in-place map implementation to exist - unless you changed its type signature, so that on some type `Collection[A]` you could only map using a function of type `A => A`.

(Edit: as other answers have pointed out, there is such a method called `transform`!)

Because `map` creates a new collection, you can go from a `Collection[A]` to a `Collection[B]` using a function `A => B`, which is much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the `map` and `:+` methods return a modified copy of the collection. More generally, all methods defined in collections from the `scala.collection` package will never modify a collection in place even when the dynamic type of the collection is from `scala.collection.mutable`. To modify a collection in place, look for methods defined in `scala.collection.mutable._` but not in `scala.collection._`.

For example, `:+` is defined in `scala.collection.Seq`, so it will never perform in-place modification even when the dynamic type is a `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`. However, `+=`, which is defined in `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` and not in `scala.collection.Seq`, will modify the collection in place.